# How to tell if ActiveDirectory connection is using LDAP?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I am in charge of an application that does an Active Directory query and have been asked if it uses LDAP. Unfortunately I know very little about the subject. I'm wondering how I would tell this.

...if we take this snippet of C# code:

```
using (PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain.Value, UserName.Value, Password.Value))
{
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);

    UserPrincipal sr = (UserPrincipal)search.FindAll().
                                             Where(c => c.SamAccountName.ToLower() == UserName.Value.ToLower()).
                                             FirstOrDefault();
```

The person who wrote this code has left the company.

`Domain.Value` is just a string containing a Windows domain.

I've done a bit of searching but all I've been able to tell so far is that LDAP is a protocol used by ActiveDirectory, but I don't know how to identify whether this particular connection is using LDAP, or perhaps ActiveDirectory always uses LDAP and the question is irrelevant?

How would I tell this?

Answer (score 1):

The `PrincipalSearcher` should provide a method [GetUnderlyingSearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.getunderlyingsearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) which should return a [DirectorySearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

From the documentation:

> Use a DirectorySearcher object to search and perform queries against an Active Directory Domain Services hierarchy using Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP).

I've not used `System.DirectoryServices` though so I'd advice some more investigation specifically on which authentication method is used.

Comment: The next sentence in that documentation is key: "LDAP is the only system-supplied Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI) provider that supports directory searching."